# Is there a performence difference between creating a button programmatically or creating it in xml?

Tags: android, xml, performance, button

I want to create 16 buttons each have different texts on it.Those text will be picked up randomly from an array depending on another random value.Lets say,

I have 3 words (apple,banana,watermelon), when the activity created it will pick up one of these words.Lets say apple.And in this activity's screen there will be 16 buttons.These buttons must have the letters that apple consists of "a","p","p","l","e" and the remaining buttons will be filled up with other remaining letters of the alphabet.

So in my case what I wonder is should i do the button creation programmatically by taking a value and assigning this value on creation one by one or do it in the xml and leave their text parts and fill up programmatically.

These 2 options in detail :

First : I'm going to create a function which takes a String value as a paramater and returns a button with this text set on it by using `setText();`  and then locate it in the layout.

Second : I create the layout with those button and leave blank their text parts and in the activity I only assign their letter values.

I vote for the second option but I'd like to know what's your opinion and would there be a difference in terms of performance or memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The disadvantage of declarative approach is that you can get only so
>   far with XML.

XML is great for look and feel of your user interface, but it does not provide a great way of handling user input. That's where the programmatic approach came.

Everything you can do declarative as well as with programmatically. **But java also allows you to specify what happens when the button is actually clicked.**

This is the main advantage of programmatic approach to the user interface.

**So what is Best ?**

Here it is , Both are good at thier point.

1) Use XML , when everything about your user interface is static , such as layout of the screen , all the widget etc.

2) Then switch to the programmatic approach when user interacts with various widget in the user interface.

> In other words you would use XML for what the button Looks like and
>   Java to specify what it does.

Comment: Thanks for replying! So your suggestion is that the texts on the buttons will be done programmatically whereas the creation of the text-free button will be in xml, right?

Comment: @Recomer : Absulately. For look and feel declare it in XML and for performing action you should it use as programtically

Comment: @Recomer : Glad to help you :-)